# Mac won't finish logging in after restart, must shut down to login completely

Tags: macos, login, restart

Not sure if this is a duplicate question (I haven't been able to find a question dealing with this yet). Here's my problem:

Currently on OSX Mavericks.

1. I restart my machine.
2. It shuts down and starts back up.
3. I get the login screen.
4. I enter in my login credentials successfully.
5. I'm passed to the interstitial white/gray screen that you typically get when starting up.
6. Instead of continuing the login process, it just hangs on this screen and never logs in.

If I shut down completely and then turn my computer on, I can log in with no issues.

Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I would look in your `Console` logs and see if anything jumps out, then edit into the question.

Comment: @stuffe is there anything I'm looking for in particular?

Comment: How long is a piece of string?!  It's really hard to say, and difficult to provide suggestions, but the best way is to make sure your phone or something is synced to the same time as the Mac, and time your crash/reboots exactly, then look through log entries for the period when you have to reboot, see what shoes up.  Sometimes it sticks out easily enough, words like "panic" and "crash" etc, other times, less so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted this question, I ran Disk Utility. I repaired some permissions. When I restarted again, it logged in properly. At this point I can't find any other issues.

I guess the moral of the story is run Disk Utility first before posting in the future.